# using YAML to get input from the user and converting it to dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have to get inputs from the user in YAML form but I can't use any external files, then I have to convert the inputs to dictionaries in which the header would be the key and other elements would be the value stored in a list.

for example, if the input is:

```
- name: ali
  age: 12
  city: bushehr
  albums:
    - bidad
    - blaze
```

the answer should be:

```
{'Ali': (12, 'Bushehr', ['bidad', 'blaze'])}
```

or for example, if the input is:

```
- name: bidad
  singer: shajarian
  genre: classic
  tracks: 10
- name: blaze
  singer: ghorbani
  genre: pop
  tracks: 9
```

the answer should be :

```
{'bidad': ('shajarian', 'classic', 10), 'blaze': ('ghorbani', 'pop', 9)}
```

a hand would mean the world to me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Read in the yaml as a list of dicts, then process the dicts. It's unclear at which point you're having trouble.

Comment: by "I can't use any external files" you mean you cannot use the pyyaml package?

Comment: i can use libraries and packages but I cant use external files to write and read from them...

Comment: @timgeb, I don't know how can I use YAML for this, to read from it and convert it to list and dictionaries, the whole thing is where I have trouble, basically.

Comment: @timgeb. I think what the OP wants it's get input data from stdin or not from a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `PyYAML` after get user input:

```
# pip install pyyaml
import yaml

data = []

print('Input your data (blank line to quit): ')
while True:
    line = input()
    if line == '':
        break
    data.append(line)
data = yaml.load('\n'.join(data), yaml.SafeLoader)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
Input your data (blank line to quit): 
- name: ali
  age: 12
  city: bushehr
  albums:
    - bidad
    - blaze

[{'name': 'ali', 'age': 12, 'city': 'bushehr', 'albums': ['bidad', 'blaze']}]
```

Comment: thank you! is there any way that the answer wouldn't have the keys after the first one? here in your code, the output is [{'name': 'ali', 'age': 12, 'city': 'bushehr', 'albums': ['bidad', 'blaze']}] but I don't need "name, age, city, and albums", the key should be the name, "here is Ali" and other elements should be only values, is there any way for doing that?